# Unresolved reference after adding a new dependency in Android Studio(Spruce Animation Library)

Tags: android, kotlin, maven, gradle

I wanted to use this cool library called Spruce made by willowtreeapps

Here is the github link : https://github.com/willowtreeapps/spruce-android#about-willowtree

In this github it says

Add the following to your project's root build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    maven {

        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/bfears/maven"
    }
}
```

Add the following to your project's build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.willowtreeapps.spruce:spruce-android:1.1.0'
}
```

In my project root when I tried to add

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/bfears/maven"
    }
   
}
```

It gave me an error saying "build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but 'maven' was added by build file'build.gradle' :15"

to fix that issue I put that maven dependency inside setting.gradle file
now all of my gradle files look like this:

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.healthcare"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')

    implementation "com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie:2.10.1"
    implementation "com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.10.1"

    implementation 'androidx.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha11'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

    implementation 'com.willowtreeapps.spruce:spruce-android:1.1.0'

}
```

setting.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/bfears/maven' }

    }
}
rootProject.name = "HealthCare"
include ':app'
```

I don't have any build errors.

What could be the issue that I get Unresolved reference in my code at Spruce

```
  val spruceAnimator = Spruce.SpruceBuilder(searchDoctorRecyclerView)
            .sortWith(DefaultSort(/* delay= */ 100L))
            .animateWith(DefaultAnimations.fadeAnimator(searchDoctorRecyclerView, /* duration= */ 800))
            .start()
```

Thanks in advance!